# Export Data to Excel in vertical

Tags: c#, excel, windows

I am export data from sql server to excel the output is came but the data is printing horizontal in excel.. but i want printing data in vertical help me to solve this... below code

like this[image]

```
    public void ExportTable(string query, string sheetName)

    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STR);
        SqlDataReader myReader = null;

        try
        {

            Excel.Worksheet oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, 1, Excel.XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            oSheet.Name = sheetName;
            previousWorksheet = oSheet;
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

            int columnCount = myReader.FieldCount;
            int rowCounter = 3;
            while (myReader.Read())

            {
                for (int n = 0; n < columnCount; n++)

                {

                    addData(oSheet, rowCounter, n + 1, myReader[myReader.GetName(n)].ToString());

                }
                rowCounter++;
            }


        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: What is the implementation of addData?

Comment: I added file in Dropbox

Comment: Can't you simply exchange the row and col-parameters in the call to addData?

Comment: Yes I found the answer